# remove default language from .htaccess seo url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slug

I rewrite multi language Url using `.htaccess` like this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(fr/en)/(article|page|gallery)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ index.php?page=$2&id=$3&title=$4&lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Output Is :

```
http://localhost/subdomain/fr/article/1/title1.html
http://localhost/subdomain/en/article/2/title2.html
```

this worked true for two language `(fr/en)`. my default language is `en` and I need to remove `en` from slug url like this :

```
 http://localhost/subdomain/article/2/title2.html
```

my mean is remove `en` from seo url only for language is default `en`. how do can I generate this ?!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Rule for "en"
RewriteRule ^(article|page|gallery)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&title=$3&lang=en [NC,L,QSA]
#____________

#Rule for "fr"
RewriteRule ^(fr)/(article|page|gallery)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ index.php?page=$2&id=$3&title=$4&lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```